# Android - ImageView with transparent space around it (in Dialog) - problem with View below it

Tags: android, imageview, android-alertdialog, android-image

I want to create this:

[image]

It's in dialog with the `CardView` and in the top/middle of the dialog I want circle `imageView` (or view) with transparent space around it. (I have a problem with background view below the image)

Is it possible to do it somehow easily? Maybe using `FloatActionButton`?

I tried several options but nothing works correctly...

Comment: Please share your code which you have tried

Comment: You just give border dark color of your imageview drawable.

Comment: Instead of background transparent, you can give the same background color right so that the background image will not visible.

Comment: No, it's not possible to add only border dark color (I need transparency). Because around the AlertDialog is dark color with transparency and if I add border dark color around it without transparency, then it won't look OK. User will notice it (that's different and not transparent around it)